# Scala akka: declare a global variable in receive function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka

I want to declare a global variable when an Actor receive some message, here is my code, it works. Q: Can I achieve that with immutable variable?

```
case class Start(configs:JobConfig)
trait Job extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  //use "val" instead
  private var confMap:Map[String,String]=Map()
  def receive = {
    case Start(conf) => {
      confMap = conf.properties
      init()
    }
      case x => log.debug("Got: " + x)
  }

  final def getProperties():Map[String,String]={
    confMap
  }

  def init()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, but if your `init` use `confMap` it should take a map as parametr:

```
...
def receive(confMap:Map[String,String] = Map()) = {
  case Start(conf) => 
    init(conf.properties)
    context.become(receive(conf.properties))
  case ...
```

You can find more information [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html)

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. But how to use confMap in other function? I don't know which function will use confMap, that'sthe main reason I declare a global variable.

Comment: If you use global variables it is producing side effect. It becomes difficult or sometimes impossible to test your functions in isolation. So, I think all of your functions should take `confMap` as parameter or you can create class which will take configs as parameter and has all methods which you need, and use it in `receive` parameter.